# I was wondering if a JavaScript programmer could help me write a javascript function to extract the x-y points from a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was wondering if a JavaScript programmer could help me write a JavaScript function to extract the x-y points 0.0, 0.0 and 5.0,5.0 from the JSON string "[{"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0}, {"y": 5.0, "x": 5.0}]".Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do your own research first. If you are really stuck with a problem you can't solve, then you could ask for help on Stack Overflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.parse();`

it transforms your string into an array.

```
var jsonStr='[{"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0}, {"y": 5.0, "x": 5.0}]';
var array=JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(array[0].x,array[1].x);
```

`array` contains everything you need.

`array[0]` is the first set of values.

`array[0].x` is the first x value.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/uXr5g/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this answer from Elias vanOotegem in StackOverflow. Thanks

---

If the string is always going to look like this: "ch[num1]sl[num2]", you can easily get the numbers without a regex like so:

var numbers = str.substr(2).split('sl');
//chop off leading ch---/\   /-- use sl to split the string into 2 parts.
In the case of "ch2sl4", numbers will look like this: ["2", "4"], coerce them to numbers like so: var num1 = +(numbers[0]), or numbers.map(function(a){ return +(a);}.

If the string parts are variable, this does it all in one fell swoop:

var str = 'ch2fsl4';
var numbers = str.match(/[0-9]+/g).map(function(n)
{//just coerce to numbers
    return +(n);
});
console.log(numbers);//[2,4]
share|edit|flag
answered Jul 25 '13 at 7:53

Elias Van Ootegem
21.7k21450

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse to get the information out

```
var i,
    jsonString = "[{"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0}, {"y": 5.0, "x": 5.0}]",
    jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

To get into the x, y coordinate you can specify the location

```
jsonObject[0].x
```

or iterate through the values with a for loop The example below prints out all of the x values

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonObject .length; i++)
{ 
   document.write(jsonObject [i].x);
}
```